# I want to migrate SQL Database to MongoDB So How I Supposed to maintain relational data?

Tags: sql, node.js, mongodb, migration, relational

I am working on a project where I have to migrate the SQL database to MongoDB. I have used Mongo 3T to migrate data to MongoDB but the Id is generated as 1,2,3,4 and so on. Now my concern is, how can I maintain the relationship in between the collections.

The pattern is like:

Devices that are at some location and these locations have different sites. If anyone has migrated the SQL database to MongoDB, please add your comment to help me. :)

Note: I am using NodeJS for the development of the API.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use an ORM which supports both SQL and MongoDB, create model files and associations .

Answer (score 0):

The relational database and document-oriented database are pretty different, so your data must be organized/structured accordingly. If your data structure does not follow the requirements/recommendations of the DBMS (database management system), then the usage of this database will be not efficient. That means that your database design is bad or was chosen the wrong DBMS (it does not meet your requirements). I do not see any reasons why you want to change the DBMS (from SQL to MongoDB) if you are planning to keep up with the current data structure. The technologies/solutions must be chosen not by popularity, but by suitable (how it meets the requirements).

The best solution depends on the project details. If we would know the reason why you want to migrate maybe we can give you better advice.

Possible solutions:

- migrate from the SQL to MongoDB, but then in most cases, you need to change your data structure.
- use both DBMS in areas where they are the best.
- keep up with the SQL DBMS, just optimize the data structure and application.

Answer (score 0):

After migrating SQL database into MongoDB if want to fetch populated result you will need to define _id in the Mongoose schema and put the ref of the model in another table. In this way, you can maintain relationship. Just use the populate method of Mongoose and you would be able to fetch data.